# Will application version <X> be available natively in Ubuntu version <Y>?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, apt-get, aptitude

Specifically I want to know if MySQL 5.7 will be available natively (fully integrated, no fiddling with repositories) in Ubuntu 15.04.

But I'm really more interested in a general answer, like, is there a website that lists out target versions for Ubuntu releases?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indeed browse Ubuntu’s package database. It’s available at [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

You can select to browse packages per release or search for specific packages on specific releases.

Since Ubuntu 15.04 is named “Vivid”, you can find anything related to MySQL using [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql&searchon=names&suite=vivid&section=all).

Since MySQL 5.7 doesn’t have a General Availability release yet, it isn’t available. It might be in the future.